# distplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'figsize'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to change the figure size of the histogram I am constructing.
I'm getting the error:

```
distplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'figsize'
```

The code I am trying to run is this:

```
sns.distplot(MSoft['pct_change'].dropna(), bins=100, color='magenta', figsize=(20,8))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the size of figure, on which plot is drawn -

```
sns.set_style('ticks')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(10, 6)
sns.distplot(MSoft['pct_change'].dropna(), bins=100, color='magenta', ax=ax)
```

Comment: That worked perfect, thank you!